# how to get the vue element calling method in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to ad an element to the array clicking the button with vue.js, maybe calling the method aggiungiViaggio on click, but how can I find on which viaggio in I'm currently in?

This is the HTML part example:

```html
    <div class="row viaggio" v-for="catalogo in cataloghi"> 
      <div class="row viaggio" v-for="viaggio in catalogo.viaggi">  
      </div>
    </div>
         <button class="bottone-aggiungi-viaggio activeButton" 
           @click="aggiungiViaggio">Aggiungi viaggio</button>
        </div>
```

This is the js:

```js
    var appCataloghi = new Vue({
      el: '#appCataloghi',
      data: {
        cataloghi: oggettoCataloghi.cataloghi
      },
      methods: {
        aggiungiViaggio: function() {
           this.viaggi.unshift({});
        }
      }
    })
```

This is the object I created the data:

> myObj= '{"cataloghi":[{"id":"1000","nome":"mete
> europee","viaggi":[{"id":"1423","nome":"primoviaggioGSpagna","nazione":"Spagna",
> "tipologia" :
> "viaggiGuidati"},{"id":"1424","nome":"secondoviaggioGSpagna","nazione":"Spagna",
> "tipologia" : "viaggiGuidati"}], "descrizione" : "Viaggi per clienti
> amanti del giappone"},{"id":"1001","nome":"viaggi
> giappone","viaggi":[{"id":"1523","nome":"scopertadelGiappone","nazione":"Giappone",
> "tipologia" :
> "itinerari"},{"id":"1524","nome":"Giappone","nazione":"Giappone",
> "tipologia" : "itinerari"}]}]}'

The method is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the item in the on click

```
<div class="row viaggio" v-for="viaggio in catalogo.viaggi"> 
 <button class="bottone-aggiungi-viaggio activeButton" @click="aggiungiViaggio(viaggio)">Aggiungi viaggio</button>
</div>
```

You can even get the index if you want

```
<div class="row viaggio" v-for="(viaggio , viaggioidx)in catalogo.viaggi"> 
 <button class="bottone-aggiungi-viaggio activeButton" @click="aggiungiViaggio(viaggioidx)">Aggiungi viaggio</button>
</div>
```

The method signature changes to accept the object.
(Also, best to clone it first and then append because that object might get edited later)

```
var appCataloghi = new Vue({
  el: '#appCataloghi',
  data: {
    cataloghi: oggettoCataloghi.cataloghi
  },
  methods: {
    aggiungiViaggio: function(viaggio) {
        var cloned = Object.extend({},viaggio); //Optional
       this.viaggi.unshift(cloned );
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have changed the nest of the question but the logic is the same, I also have to add an argument called for example 'obj' to my method right? 
methods: {
    aggiungiViaggio: function(obj) {
       obj.viaggi.unshift({});
    }
  }